# Ignore component scan when all tests are ignored

Tags: java, spring, teamcity

Is there a way to ignore component scan when all tests are ignored ?

Let's say I have test like this and all tests in class are ignored

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class ReqMigration {
    //.... all tests are ignored
}
```

TestConfig.class looks like this

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "file:${path.app}/configuration/env.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
@PropertySource(value= "classpath:migration-test.properties")
@Import({BpmConfig.class, MonitorConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles({"monitor-elasticsearch"})
public class TestConfig {
     ...
}
```

The problem is when I push such a test and run build in CI (Teamcity) it still tries to scan everything defined in **TestConfig.class** even all tests are ignored. Can I override somehow this behaviour ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Any specific reason?

Comment: I am writing test for migration where I need to connect to real elasticsearch (not mock) however real elasticsearch is not available in build in teamcity. Normally when I write test I am using mocks however this is "migration test" so I need to connect to real elasticsearch which cause fail build in teamcity because it has no access to it.

Comment: I don't like that teamcity is trying to access to everything defined in config even though it don't have to run any tests at all